# How to control raster file sizes in R

Tags: r, raster, filesize

When I re-project my raster (gridded climate data) from one projection to another the file size blows up. Do you know any way to control this.?
Here is an example

```
library(raster)

## reading and raster files to be reprojected###
setwd ("E:/PhD BOKU/DATA/CLIMATE_EU/Normal_1961-1990_Bioclimatic_1km")

clim <- list.files(pattern =".asc", full.names=F)

s<- stack(clim)

## projectingraster to geographic projection might 
newproj <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")

ClimEU_WGS84 <-  projectRaster(s, crs= newproj,res= 0.008333334)

####  writing the newly reprojected rasters into another folder
setwd("E:/PhD BOKU/DATA/CLIMATE_EU/Normal_1961-1990_Bioclimatic_1km_WGS84")

writeRaster(ClimEU_WGS84,filename=names(ClimEU_WGS84), bylayer=TRUE,format="ascii",overwrite=T)
```

Comment: Another way to make files smaller is to round and save as integer (see `?dataType`.

Comment: better than below answer +1

Answer (score 0):

There are different tricks, but the most important one is, by far:

--  Do not use ASCII format for storing large rasters!

Use, for example, GeoTIFF. That format has compression options. See ?writeRaster